# PHP script to list hyperlinks?

Tags: php

I have a website that handles streamed content. With the general nature of the site though we generally have to update it weekly. This means adding a new page every week for each new streaming episode.

I know enough PHP to be dangerous so to speak. I store each new webpage in a folder. The folder is appropriately titled the name of the streaming series. I want to create some PHP code that grabs all the pages names in the directory and outputs them as hyperlinks. This way I don't have to manually do this every week PLUS update all the old pages with the new link.

THANKS!

Comment: glob() for the file names then foreach() through the array creating the html. Someone will probably post an answer with the whole thing, but you will learn more if you do it your self.

Comment: Dagon is right, if you post an excerpt of your directory structure as example I'd volunteer to be 'someone' :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below and you should edit the **$fullPath**, **$relativePath**, **$filter** and **$after** Variables.

**$fullPath** is your directory's exact path on the computer.

**$relativePath**'s value should be relative to your page which you're using this script in it (you can find more info about paths here http://bit.ly/fCbRDh)

And **$filter**'s values are optional. You can add or edit respectively as i do. It's for filtering links extensions or much more, so your document extensions will not be on your page link's texts.

**$after** is optional too. It's creating new line after the links right now, you can change it to whatever you want.

```
<?php
$fullPath = 'C:/ROOT/project/';
$relativePath = '../pages/';
$filter = array('.html', '.htm', '.php');
$after = '<br />';

if ($handle = opendir($fullPath)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $href = $relativePath . $file;
        echo '<a href="' . $href . '">' . str_replace($filter, '', $file) . "</a>\n" . $after;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: i think glob() would make it a lot easier.